# Mongo: Get the first document of each group with a matching condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have model for messages with a date, txt, sender and receiver. I need to get the last message between two users, for example:

```
{_id: 1, sender:1, receiver:2, txt: “hi 2”, date: “2018/04/01”}
{_id: 2, sender:1, receiver:2, txt: “how are you 2”, date: “2018/04/02”}
{_id: 3, sender:2, receiver:1, txt: “hi 1”, date: “2018/04/03”}
{_id: 4, sender:1, receiver:3, txt: “hi 3”, date: “2018/04/01”}
{_id: 5, sender:1, receiver:3, txt: “how are you 3”, date: “2018/04/02”}
```

If I’m looking for new messages involving user 1, I would need:

```
{_id: 3, sender:2, receiver:1, txt: “hi 1”, date: “2018/04/03”}
{_id: 5, sender:1, receiver:3, txt: “how are you 3”, date: “2018/04/02”}
```

If not possible to group them in a way in which the user can be either sender or receiver then, this would also be fine:

```
{_id: 2, sender:1, receiver:2, txt: “how are you 2”, date: “2018/04/02”}
{_id: 3, sender:2, receiver:1, txt: “hi 1”, date: “2018/04/03”}
{_id: 5, sender:1, receiver:3, txt: “how are you 3”, date: “2018/04/02”}
```

What do you guys think? Is it possible to do this with mongo/mongoose? I was looking at aggregations and groups, but I'm not too familiar with those.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            "sender": [
                {$match: {"sender" : 1}},
                {$sort: {_id: -1}},
                {$limit:1}
            ],
            "receiver": [
                {$match: {"receiver" : 1}},
                {$sort: {_id: -1}},
                {$limit:1}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            sender: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$sender", 0 ] },
            receiver: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$receiver", 0 ] }
        }
    }
])
```